# Using protobuf, how to remove a field from a parsed object?

Tags: python, field, protocol-buffers

I have parsed successfully a proto buffer into my object and can display or modify my fields:

```
print "convolution param = " + str(net.layer[1].convolution_param)
net.layer[1].convolution_param.num_output = 0
```

returns

```
convolution param = num_output: 64
pad: 1
kernel_size: 3
```

However, I am trying to remove convolution_param altogether and can't:

```
del net.layer[1].convolution_param
```

returns

```
del net.layer[1].convolution_param
TypeError: Can't set composite field
```

I believe this is what triggers this error in the [source](http://eion.robbmob.com/hangouts/protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/python/google/protobuf/pyext/message.cc) of the proto library:

```
int SetAttr(CMessage* self, PyObject* name, PyObject* value) {
  if (PyDict_Contains(self->composite_fields, name)) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Can't set composite field");
    return -1;
  }
```

What is the prescribed method for removing a field? I also tried without more success the following:

```
del net.layer[1].convolution_param.num_output
del net.layer[1].convolution_param[:] = []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success with:

```
del net.layer[1].convolution_param[:]
```

Removing the braces will cause the above mentioned error.